# Full-text search on subclass returns java.lang.illegalArgumentException: too many full-text indices on given class: Customer

Tags: lucene, polymorphism, full-text-search, orientdb

I want to create full-text index on all vertices, including subclasses, using lucene.

Class Person has property name.
Class Customer inherits from Person and has property customer_id.

Creating full-text index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX Person.fulltext ON Person(name) FULLTEXT ENGINE LUCENE
CREATE INDEX Customer.fulltext ON Person(name, customer_id) FULLTEXT ENGINE LUCENE
```

Searching for Customer like this:

```
SELECT FROM Customer WHERE SEARCH_CLASS("id123") = true
```

I want to retrive the customer by matching on name or customer_id but get illegalArgumentException: too many full-text indices on ginen class: Customer.
How should I create the index to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not exactly what I was looking for but I solved it with these changes:

Class Person has property name.
Class Customer **does not** inherit from Person and has property customer_id **and name**.

Creating full-text index the same way.

Searching for Customer and Person like this:

```
SELECT EXPAND($a) 
LET 
  $b=(SELECT FROM Customer WHERE SEARCH_CLASS("id123")=true), 
  $c=(SELECT FROM Person WHERE SEARCH_CLASS("id123")=true), 
  $a=UNIONALL($b, $c)
```